# setting height and width of canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

When I do

```
canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
```

I get no problems.

When I do

```
canvas.style.width=window.innerWidth;
```

The canvas remains at its default width.

When I do

```
canvas.width(window.innerWidth);
```

I get "Uncaught typeError: number is not a function". I have no variables or functions called "canvas", "width", "window", or "innerWidth".

Why does only the first method work?

Comment: The two first ways work, the third one of course does not (`width` is not a function). If the second way does not produce the desired effect, then you have something else that overrides its effect (or the code is not executed at all). Provide a real example that actually demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because canvas has `width`and `height`as attributes also Each time the height or width of a canvas is re-set, the canvas content will be cleared. That's why your first approach has worked.

Answer (score 0):

`width` is a property, not a function, thus the error. The `width` property of the canvas element affects the canvas context while the `style.width` applies to the HTML element only, so it will stretch the context if this value is higher.